# Variadic template pack expansion fails with VS2017 RC but not VS2015

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The test program compiles with VS2015 but not with VS2017 RC. Below is the error I am getting while compiling the test program with VS2017 RC:

```
/* main.cpp */
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct A_impl
{
    using type = std::false_type;
};

template <typename T>
using A = typename A_impl<T>::type;

template <bool... B>
struct logic_helper;

template <bool... B>
using none_t = std::is_same<logic_helper<B...>, logic_helper<(B && false)...>>;

template <typename... C>
struct Foo
{
    // Compile error:
    // error C3520: 'C': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
    using FooType = none_t<A<C>::value...>;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int, int, int> foo;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know why the newest Visual Studio fails to compile the code while the older version has no problem with it. If possible, is there a solution to this compile error for VS2017 RC?

Comment: File an issue on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: Are you running the [latest version of Visual Studio 2017?](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#feb7)

Comment: I believe so because I installed VS2017 just yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to the problem, but I still can't understand why the compiler complains with my first approach:

```
template <typename... C>
struct Foo
{
    // Workaround
    using FooType2 = logic_helper<A<C>::value...>;
    using FooType3 = logic_helper<(A<C>::value && false)...>;
    using FooType4 = std::is_same<FooType2, FooType3>;
};
```